# sql query to make a discontinous time series as continous time series

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am trying to run a sql query in Oracle 11g which will transform the below given data set to the next data set.

```
id| start date1       | end date1          |   start date2      | end date2
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1 | 27/02/2017 01:00:00| 27/02/2017 02:00:00| 27/02/2017 01:00:00|27/02/2017 02:00:00
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2 | 27/02/2017 02:00:00| 27/02/2017 04:00:00| 27/02/2017 02:00:00|27/02/2017 03:00:00
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2 | 27/02/2017 02:00:00| 27/02/2017 04:00:00| 27/02/2017 03:00:00|27/02/2017 03:30:00
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 3 | 27/02/2017 04:00:00| 27/02/2017 05:00:00| 27/02/2017 04:00:00|27/02/2017 05:00:00
----------

Final dataset :

id | start date1       | end date1          | start date2        | end date2
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1 | 27/02/2017 01:00:00| 27/02/2017 02:00:00| 27/02/2017 01:00:00|27/02/2017 02:00:00
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2 | 27/02/2017 02:00:00| 27/02/2017 04:00:00| 27/02/2017 02:00:00|27/02/2017 03:00:00
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2 | 27/02/2017 02:00:00| 27/02/2017 04:00:00| 27/02/2017 03:00:00|27/02/2017 03:30:00
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2 | 27/02/2017 02:00:00| 27/02/2017 04:00:00| 27/02/2017 03:30:00|27/02/2017 04:00:00
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 3 | 27/02/2017 04:00:00| 27/02/2017 05:00:00| 27/02/2017 04:00:00|27/02/2017 05:00:00
----------
```

The logic of this is that the start date1 and end date1 will be continuous. Also the start_date2 and end date2 needs to be continuous. If at some point end date2 is not matching with the next startdate2 , then a new row needs be added having the same id and having enddate2 as the next start date1.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: the model clause could probably handle this. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/bi-foundation/10gr1-twp-bi-dw-sqlmodel-131067.pdf  it is a big challenging to use however

Comment: What are the assumptions? Is every interval on the right guaranteed to be contained in the interval on the left? Are two intervals on the right, both with the same interval on the left, guarantee not to overlap except for the enddate2 of one being equal to the startdate2 of the other?

Comment: And... what real life problem/situation is modeled in this table? It's a very poor design, if you have any say in it we can likely come up with a much better one.

Comment: @mathguy , Yes sir , both the assumptions are correct. Its actually a problem i am facing but have simplified it down to the one given above.

Comment: @amit - the reason I ask is this: if your first table is not stored that way on disk, but instead it is the result of other computations, it doesn't make sense to generate it in that format, only to dis-assemble it (perhaps with `UNPIVOT` or `UNION ALL` etc., do more computations, and then aggregate it again. It makes much more sense to get the results **directly** in the desired format.

Answer (score 0):

For example I make next query

```
with s (id,start_date1,end_date1,start_date2,end_date2) as 
(select 
1, to_date('27/02/2017 01:00:00','dd/mm/yyyy HH24:MI:SS'), to_date('27/02/2017 02:00:00','dd/mm/yyyy HH24:MI:SS'), 
to_date('27/02/2017 01:00:00','dd/mm/yyyy HH24:MI:SS'), to_date('27/02/2017 02:00:00','dd/mm/yyyy HH24:MI:SS') from dual union all
select 2, to_date('27/02/2017 02:00:00','dd/mm/yyyy HH24:MI:SS'), to_date('27/02/2017 04:00:00','dd/mm/yyyy HH24:MI:SS'), 
to_date('27/02/2017 02:00:00','dd/mm/yyyy HH24:MI:SS'), to_date('27/02/2017 03:00:00','dd/mm/yyyy HH24:MI:SS') from dual union all
select 2, to_date('27/02/2017 02:00:00','dd/mm/yyyy HH24:MI:SS'), to_date('27/02/2017 04:00:00','dd/mm/yyyy HH24:MI:SS'), 
to_date('27/02/2017 03:00:00','dd/mm/yyyy HH24:MI:SS'), to_date('27/02/2017 03:30:00','dd/mm/yyyy HH24:MI:SS') from dual union all
select 3, to_date('27/02/2017 04:00:00','dd/mm/yyyy HH24:MI:SS'), to_date('27/02/2017 05:00:00','dd/mm/yyyy HH24:MI:SS'), 
to_date('27/02/2017 04:00:00','dd/mm/yyyy HH24:MI:SS'), to_date('27/02/2017 05:00:00','dd/mm/yyyy HH24:MI:SS') from dual
)
select distinct
id,sd1, ed1,  sd2, ed2 from (
select id,
       to_char(sd1,'dd/mm/yyyy HH24:MI:SS') sd1,
       to_char(ed1,'dd/mm/yyyy HH24:MI:SS') ed1, 
       to_char(border,'dd/mm/yyyy HH24:MI:SS') as sd2, 
       to_char(nvl(lead(border) over (partition by sd1, ed1 order by border),ed1),'dd/mm/yyyy HH24:MI:SS') as ed2  
from (
select id,
       start_date1 as sd1,
       end_date1 as ed1 ,
       decode(id1, 0,start_date2,end_date2)   as border,
       start_date2 as sd2 ,
       end_date2 as ed2,
       id1
       from s
       join (select rownum -1 as id1 from dual connect by level <= 2) on 1=1 )) 
where sd2 < ed2;
```

Comment: Hi @TomJMuthirenthi. `Connect by level < smth` - genereate additional rows with table or subquery. ANy level will generate `power(level, rows)` number of rows where rows - it's count of rows in main table

Comment: So, here the logic worked because we had the ID(int) column, Isn't?

Comment: well, you may say so. But realy, its just need for duplicate rows in first table.

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar with Microsoft SQL server. And this is what I have used:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Results') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Results

CREATE TABLE #Results ( 
MonthYear DATE,
[Month] INT, 
[Year] INT                         
)

DECLARE @Y1 INT = 2019, @Y2 INT = 2020, @M1 INT = 1, @M2 INT = 12

WHILE @Y1 <= @Y2
BEGIN
        WHILE @M1 <= @M2
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO #Results (MonthYear, [Month], [Year])
            VALUES(DATEFROMPARTS(@Y1,@M1,1),@M1,@Y1)
            SET @M1 = @M1+1
        END
        SET @Y1 = @Y1 + 1
END

SELECT R.MonthYear,
COUNT(T.CreatedOn) AS [Counts]
FROM #Results R
LEFT JOIN MyTable T ON DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, T.CreatedOn), 0) = R.MonthYear
GROUP BY MonthYear
```

---

So, if the actual grouped data is like this:

[image]

The transformed series (with continuous monthly data, i.e. all missing months filled) looks like this:
[image]